# Get the number of rows in query with Knex

Tags: knex.js

For example...

```
const knex = require('knex')(knexConfig);

function getItem(page) {
  knex('items').select(/** select statement here */);

  if (condition) {
    knex.where(/** add where clause*/);
  }

  // There isn't such a function as "countRows()", I just want to have something like this
  const totalRows = knex.countRows();

  return {
    data: await knex.limit(50).offset(page),
    totalRows: totalRows,
  } 
}
```

This function can return the first 50 items, but it also has to return the total number of items too.

```
const totalRows = await knex.clone().length;
```

This works, but it can take too long, because the `items` table is quite huge (over 10k rows).

```
const totalRows = await knex.clone().count('*');
```

This will simply add `count` column into each row, so I can't get the total number of rows. The `select` statement that's defined in the beginning of this function can't be changed, so I'm not sure if I can use `count` to get the number.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could potentially do is to clone your initial select query, then clear the select part of it using `.clearSelect()` so you still keep the table + where clause and then add a count. So something like:

```js
function getItem(page) {
  const selectQuery = knex('items').select(/** select statement here */);

  if (condition) {
    selectQuery.where(/** add where clause*/);
  }

  const countQuery = selectQuery.clone().clearSelect().count('* as totalRows').first();

  const data = await selectQuery.limit(50).offset(page);
  const { totalRows } = await countQuery;

  return {
    data,
    totalRows,
  } 
}
```